# zsh terminal output show key value when run mongod

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal, zsh

I am installing and using mongodb. However during the execution of the `mongod` command the output displayed on zsh is really too annoying to my eyes. They are displayed as key values, not as complete sentences. How can I fix this. I am using Macbook Pro M1. Default terminal runs with zsh.

Please help me! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from mongod 4.4 the log messages are sent in JSON format as explained [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/) , you may use jq to parse this logs to more suitable console format.

Example:

```
cat mongod.log | tail -1 | jq
```

Some more examples on parsing mongo log messages can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#std-label-log-message-parsing)